# is there any way to change apostrophe cms login url?

Tags: express, apostrophe-cms

Currently apostrophe cms login url is `/login`

How to change it to some other url ??

example: `/sample_login`

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible because the URL is hardcoded in `lib/modules/apostrophe-login/index.js`. However it would be a very simple pull request to have this be `self.options.loginUrl`, with a default of `/login`. A similar change would make sense for the `/password-reset-request` route and those related to it.